# Is it a security risk to link OAuth logins with the same email, but different providers?

Tags: security, oauth, auth0

I am using Auth0 and OAuth to secure my site.  At the moment logging in via email, Facebook and Google all link to the same user account.  I essentially login based on email, regardless of the OAuth service provider. It seems simpler and less confusing.

But, is this a security risk?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to make each OAuth provider generate a different user account - I think this is the safest option.

Answer (score 0):

I link the accounts if the primary email of the OAuth account is verified.

Illustration:

- First, a user creates an account using email `abc@example.com`.
- Then, some days later, user tries to log in via OAuch using a Facebook account which has the same email `abc@example.com`. If Facebook's API mentions that this email is verified, I will link the account. It makes sense to link the accounts since the user has already verified their email with Facebook.